# How to connect spark to neo4j in IDE

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, database-connection, configuration-files

Is there no way to connect Spark and Neo4j without using the Spark shell? I have tried the Neo4jREST API and finding something in the Conf files, but I don't see any driver/connector that establishes a connection between the two programs so that I can query from my code.

EDIT: This is the error I'm running into.

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unsupported authentication token, scheme='none' only allowed when auth is disabled: { scheme='none' }
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketResponseHandler.handleFailureMessage(SocketResponseHandler.java:68)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.unpackFailureMessage(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:456)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:417)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.receiveOne(SocketClient.java:128)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnection.receiveOne(SocketConnection.java:135)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.receiveOne(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:150)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.PooledConnection.receiveOne(PooledConnection.java:142)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.tryFetchNext(InternalStatementResult.java:303)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.hasNext(InternalStatementResult.java:181)
at org.neo4j.spark.Executor$.execute(Neo4j.scala:399)
at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4jRDD.compute(Neo4j.scala:445)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

With this code trying to establish a connection:

```
val driver: Driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", 
AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "password"))
val session = driver.session()

val query = neo.cypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n.name").partitions(5).batch(10000).loadDataFrame()
println(query.show())

session.close()
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to change the "password" to the one you set and make sure that the username has been specified correctly.